# HTTP basic authentication policies is not reflecting to specific method and resource in mule 3

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

I've applied HTTP basic authentication in my mule application. When I am applying this for all resource and methods that time authentication is working but while doing this for specific resorce and method then HTTP basic authentication is not working or it's not asking for username and password.

I have applied auto-discovery currently.

I have 3 resource in the RAMP.
/employees, /employees/{id}, /departments

I am applying policy for /department.
How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please share some more details? For instance, relevant parts of RAML and configuration XMLs.

Comment: Additionally add the errors, and capture Http wire logging for both a working case and a failing case (masking the actual credentials)